# How can i access the current hash location on react router 2?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to access the current location path (like /home) without the history keys for some comparison logic.

How can i access it from the hashHistory in react router 2.

Also, how can i access the previous path?

Comment: Do you want to read URL hash? What about `window.location.hash`?

Comment: when i use location.hash i get react keys along with the hash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can obtain the current pathname from the `location` prop of your route component.

> Access location from this.props.location of your Route component. If
>   you'd like to get it deeper in the tree, you can use whatever
>   conventions your app has for getting props from high down low. One
>   option is to provide it on context yourself:
>
> // v2.0.x const RouteComponent = React.createClass({
>   childContextTypes: {
>       location: React.PropTypes.object   },
>
> getChildContext() {
>       return { location: this.props.location }   } })

Have a look [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#accessing-location).

To get the current path, you can just use `location.pathname`.

Comment: can you give some more details about what you want to achieve? Also, do you need to access this outside of a route component? Using `location.pathname` is the official way of getting access to the location path, but there usually are some unsupported unofficial ways, depends on what you want to do :-)

Comment: i need to access the current path that is routed. like localhost:9000/#/home.
I want 'home' to compare it. The problem with react is that is i get react keys when i use location.hash, and location.pathname gives me / all the time

Comment: That is weird. It is pretty difficult to find out the problem without seeing the code. I created [a small example](http://codepen.io/alexchiri/pen/bpVXbd) on codepen. `MainLayout` is mapped to `/` and displays inside it children `Home` and `UserList`. `UserList` is mapped to `/users` and displays child `User` inside. `User` is mapped to `/users/:id` and doesn't have any children. In the render method of each of these components I display the `location.pathname` from their props. As you can notice, when navigating to a child even the `location.pathname` of its hosting parent is changed.

Comment: Even if you get this working, I guess it's not precisely what you want, because `pathname` returns the full path, where you're probably interested in just the last bit, but it's a start :-) Hope it helps you go further, let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 6):

One way to access path is via `this.props.location` from a react component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { browserHistory, Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let location = this.props.location
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Child Component</h1>
        <p>{location.pathname}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="child" component={Child} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('example'))
```

Another way if you want listen to changes in current location via history -

```
import { createHistory } from 'history'

let history = createHistory()

// Listen for changes to the current location. The
// listener is called once immediately.
let unlisten = history.listen(function (location) {
  console.log(location.pathname)
})

// When you're finished, stop the listener.
unlisten()
```